# Animate a page alone (Appear, Enter and Leave) with ReactTransitionGroup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, reactcsstransitiongroup

I try to animate page transitions with React-router and ReactTransitionGroup.

Each page must have different transitions.

```
<ReactTransitionGroup component="div" className="animationContainer" {...this.props}>
  <Login />
</ReactTransitionGroup>
```

Like this, the component just run `componentWillAppear`. I want to set the Leave transition too.

What's the best way to handle these correctly?

This is how i try to handle the ReactTransitionGroup for now:

```
// App.js
render() {
    const { children, loggedIn, user, application } = this.props;

    const intlData = {
      locale: application.locale,
      messages: i18n[application.locale],
    };

    return (
      <IntlProvider key="intl" {...intlData}>
        <div id="application">
          <div className="page-wrap">
            <Header loggedIn={ loggedIn } user={ user } handleLogout={ this.handleLogout } handleLanguageChange={this.handleLanguageChange} />
            <MainNavigation />
            <ReactTransitionGroup component="div" className="animationContainer" {...this.props}>
              {React.cloneElement(children, {
                key: this.props.location.pathname,
              })}
            </ReactTransitionGroup>
          </div>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </IntlProvider>
    );
  }
```

And i try to create an appear, enter and leave animation for my login component.

```
  // login.js
  componentWillLeave(callback) {
    setTimeout(callback, 2000);
    console.log('componentWillLeave'); // doesn't log
  }

  /**
   * Reçoit les valeurs des formulaires
   */
  handleFormSubmit(data) {
    const { dispatch } = this.props;

    dispatch(fetchLoginAuth(data));
  }

  /**
   * Render le component - ReactTransitionGroup
   * @return {JSX} Rend la page Registration
   */
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="login-page">
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-2">
              <Link to="/" className="home-link"><img src={BASE_URL + '/assets/img/logo.svg'} alt="logo" /></Link>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
              <h1><FormattedMessage {...messages.loginPageTitle} /></h1>
            </div>
          </div>
          {React.cloneElement(this.props.children || <div />, { onSubmit: this.handleFormSubmit, login: this.props.login })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

This setup is the same thing than my registration page and forms states and in registration, it works.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The inner component will execute all of these functions which you can use to set the enter and leave behavior.

```
componentWillAppear(callback) {
  setTimeout(callback, 1);
}

componentDidAppear() {
  this._setEnterStyle();
}

componentWillEnter(callback) {
  setTimeout(callback, 1);
}

componentDidEnter() {
  this._setEnterStyle();
}

componentWillLeave(callback) {
  this._setLeaveStyle();
  setTimeout(callback, 500);
}
```

So your Login component will execute those since it is wrapped by the transition group.

Comment: I know that... But the componentWillLeave won't work. Is it possible it's because i click on a link made with react-router?

Comment: have you tried specifically using the setTimeout I mentioned in the method? I believe the delay set to that needs to be about as long as the animation should last. I do not see why react router would interfere.

Comment: I try a lot of thing and yours was the first thing i tried :S Thank you for your help! I'm just very lost now...

Comment: Ok, so the only thing that will cause that to NOT fire is if you don't actually remove the child from react transition group. You have to COMPLETELY not include the child with that id for the animation to execute. If you have the same id staying in there React will think it just changed rather than delete.

Comment: How can i handle this? I tried to set a state `renderingComp: false`, when the state is false i render a <span> and i set a setTimeout to change the state to true and render the component but it won't work. I upvote your answers to thank you.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ta410nwc/2/  Simple breakdown usage. You just include or don't include the element in the returned render.

If your component does not fire the leave code, then somehow you're still including the element in the render. I recommend debugging there and ensure the component does not get included.

Comment: It doesn't work when i change page :S If it's only standalone, it's ok

Comment: In the case of react-router this is all I could drum up. I wasn't putting it all together in my head that the router was the issue: https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/17